# FLASK -Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Tags: python, flask, iis

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
handler = **import**(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\essldatamapping\app.py", line 2, in 
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'

## MY CODE

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import pyodbc

app = Flask(**name**)
api = Api(app)
class EsslDataFeth(Resource):
def **init**(self):
server = 'ESSL-CONFIGURAT\ESSL'
database = '**'
username = '**'
password = '**'
self.connect  = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=no;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()

```
    def get(self):
        getdatacmd='SELECT * from [etimetracklite1].[dbo].[Entry_Exit]'
        self.cursor.execute(getdatacmd)
        result=[]
        for row in self.cursor.fetchall():
            item_dist={}
            item_dist['id']=row[0]
            item_dist['dateTime']=row[1]
            item_dist['INOut']=row[2]
            item_dist['DeviceID']=row[3]
            result.append(item_dist)
        return jsonify(result)
```

api.add_resource(EsslDataFeth, '/returnjson')
if **name** == '**main**':
app.run()

Comment: You will need HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: "**Api ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'**". This error indicates a module import error in your code, you need to make sure that the flask_restful module is properly installed in your Python environment. You can install it with: `pip install flask-restful` After installing the module, restart your application.